# Create formula dynamically without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I have input data in column A and some complicated formula in Column B as a function of data in A. How many rows of data in A depends on user input. It can be anywhere from 2 to 100,000. Traditionally I will populate all 100,000 rows of Column B with the same formula. But that introduces a huge overhead of unnecessary formula evaluation if only two rows of column A are used.

If VBA is allowed, it can be as easy as write a 'For' loop. But I want to know if this is possible without VBA.

Is it possible to dynamically add/remove the formula in column B with worksheet function only?

Comment: Where/How are you populating the formula? You could use CountIf to see how many values are actually populated: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/COUNTIF-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4?CorrelationId=57ff72ca-4ae0-4c7a-977e-904c028e4792&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: you will have to use VBA as there is no formula to populate a formula in a cell.

Comment: Without VBA you are going to have to have a formula in each cell.  Now that being said, if you want to cut down on the calculation time it is plausible that you could make a formula that expanded a _whole_ column and still was time efficient in calculation.

Comment: Looks like vba is inevitable for a dynamic formula adding/removing. I just try to avoid any expensive formula evaluation on the calculation chain if the input is null. Maybe a simple if logic to test the presence of input before any expensive formula would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Put the data and formulas inside a `Table` so that each time you tab down to the next row, the formula column will automatically size with the table and populate the formula along with it.